# Add reference of wlanapi.dll in windows 8

Tags: wlanapi

I want to measure signal strength of Wifi by using wlanapi function.My code is giving me error on using NativeWifi statement. How do i add reference to wlanapi.dll in windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download the dll from codeplex. Just search for nativewifi codeex. Then add reference to this dll using visual studio (right click -> Add reference)